# Cómo usar el htaccess para crear url amigables en el href con php?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Tengo un `.htaccess` para crear url amigables, recién comienzo con esta técnica pero tengo un problema, por ejemplo tengo una listas con varios `href` uno es "crear" otro "ver", cuando ingreso a "crear" me muestra `promociones/crear` en la url esta bien, pero cuando voy a "ver" me muestra `promociones/crear/ver` y eso es por que el `href` de ver puse "ver" lo que debería mostrar el url es `promociones/ver` y borrar el "crear" como hago eso gracias

Código htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

AddCharset utf-8 .php

<Files *.css>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</Files>

<Files *.js>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</Files>


###ExpiresActive on
#ExpiresDefault A0
#ExpiresDefault "access plus 6 months"
#ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 weeks"

# 1 AÑO
###<FilesMatch "\.(flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav)$">
###ExpiresDefault A14400
###</FilesMatch>

# 1 SEMANA
###<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
###ExpiresDefault A7200
###</FilesMatch>

# 1 SEMANA
###<FilesMatch "\.(txt|xml|js|css|htm|html|php)$">
###ExpiresDefault A7200
###</FilesMatch>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Activar RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^/$ tecdeco/panel/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^Admin/?$ tecdeco/panel/admin.php [L]
RewriteRule ^promociones/crear/?$ tecdeco/panel/crear_promociones.php [L]
RewriteRule ^promociones/ver/?$ tecdeco/panel/ver_promociones.php [L]





</IfModule>

# Google Analytics Integration - Added by cPanel.
<IfModule mod_substitute.c>
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
Substitute "s|(<script src='/google_analytics_auto.js'></script>)?</head>|<script src='/google_analytics_auto.js'></script></head>|i"
</IfModule>
# END Google Analytics Integration

# Con especificamos cache
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"
ExpiresByType t

ext/css "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 3 months"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/x-icon "access plus 3 months"
</IfModule>
# FIN
```

código php

```
<?php
$bandera = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

?>

<header class="main-header">
        <!-- Logo -->
        <a href="Admin.php" class="logo">
          <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
          <span class="logo-mini"><b></b>MM</span>
          <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
          <span class="logo-lg"><b>Tec Deco</b></span>
        </a>
        <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
          <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
          <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>
          <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li>
                <a href="logout.php" ><i class="fa fa-user-times"></i></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
      <aside class="main-sidebar  skin-black">
        <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
        <section class="sidebar">
          <!-- Sidebar user panel -->
          <div class="user-panel" style="height: 80px;" >
            <div class="pull-left image">
              <img src="./dist/img/perfil.png" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
            </div>
            <div class="pull-left info">
                <p style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: 10px; "></p>

                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i>Administrador</a>


            </div>
          </div>
          <li class="header">MENU DE NAVEGACION</li>  

               <li>
                  <a href="Admin.php">
                    <i class="fa fa-th"></i> <span>Inicio</span>
                  </a>
                </li>

              <li>

                  <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Promociones</span><i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                  </a>

                  <ul class="treeview-menu">
                      <li  > <a href="promociones/crear"> <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Crear promocion</a></li>
                      <li  ><a href="promociones/ver"> <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Ver promociones</a></li>
                  </ul>

              </li>



          </ul>
        </section>
        <!-- /.sidebar -->
      </aside>
```

Comment: prueba usando urls absolutas en tus links. Por ejemplo `/promociones/ver` con un slash al principio

Comment: puedes usar php .. creando un campo en la bd llamada url y luego mostrar el resultado de ese campo por le metodo get

Answer (score 0):

En principio no deberias tener problemas en navegar entre las url usando `./` y `../`.
Es decir, para navegar entre urls amigables,lo tienes que hacer igual que entre normales. Si estas en home/crear y quieres ir a home/ver solo deberías buscar la "zona" ver dentro de la actual usando `./`. Para volver hacia atrás usa `../`

```html
<h3>En la Homepage</h3>
<li><a href="promociones/crear"> <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Crear promocion</a></li>
<li><a href="promociones/ver"> <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Ver promociones</a></li>

<h3>En la Crear promocion</h3>
<li><a href="./ver"> <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Ver promociones</a></li>

<h3>En la Ver promocion</h3>
<li><a href="./crear"> <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Crear promocion</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo haces mediante reglas en tu archivo htacces

## dentro de tu archivo htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
Rewriterule perfil                                  perfil.php
```

La regla que acabo de usar es el nombre que quieres usar en tus otros archivos con el href para redireccionar, a su lado el nombre del archivo con la extexion

Ahora en tu archivo donde creas las redirecciones 
solo debes colocar `href="perfil"` para ir al perfil.php dejando en tu url perfil

```
<a href="perfil"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Inicio</a>
```

Espero que te haya ayudado mi respuesta.